# Sound on [every global] keypress (linux)

Tags: python, linux, audio, keypress

im trying to find/write a simple daemon in python (preferably) to play a sound on every key pressed, for usability purposes. Something like this https://www.grc.com/freeware/clickey.htm but for Linux.

Ive found some codes around but still cannot put them together. If you guys could point me in the right direction, it would be great

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what have you got so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will give you easiest work around:

http://www.speech.kth.se/snack/

After this you can use following code:

```
s = Sound() 
s.read('mymusic.mp3') 
s.play()
```

Good thing is that it works on both windows and linux.

Comment: hi. that code didnt work. "theres no such module" error. 
i tried pygame, it worked but im still trying to make the script wait in background and when any key is pressed, play a sound. 
thanx

Comment: @legion1978 You can make the script run in backgroud using this linux command `&`.

Comment: yes thats what im trying to put together :) i figure finding a command  to play the sound inside a loop waiting for a keypress.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the [Qwertickle](https://github.com/aitjcize/Qwertickle/) typewriter sound scheme pretty easy to learn and modify for own needs. Here is [my version](https://github.com/artemrizhov/Qwertickle) with pc keyboard sounds :)

Comment: outstanding. the typewriter version is in the AUR :)  though i cannot edit them sounds, just the default.
whats the difference to your version? can i compile it no arch (manjaro)

Comment: My version just contains another sounds, and also works on KeyRelease. I've compiled it on Ubuntu.